# How to put the characters of a 16 byte char array into a 16 byte u_int32_t array?

Tags: c

Say I have a char pointer and I want to put it into a char array with 16 characters (even if the char pointer's strlen() is greater than that, then truncate), simple enough, I just do:

```
char* pointer = <insert whatever here>;
unsigned char myArray[16];
memcpy(myArray, pointer, 16);
```

Now, I want to put the char array into a 16 byte u_int32_t array.
Here is what I am trying:

```
u_int32_t newArray[4];
memcpy(newArray, myArray, 16);
```

This doesn't seem to be copying over the bytes how I want it to. Am I missing some fundamental C step here?
Is there a different way I am supposed to put a char array into a u_int32_t array?

Comment: `memcpy` is not concerned with the types of the things you are copying. You need a loop, copying each element and possibly casting or converting it into to the appropriate type before assigning.

Comment: Please describe the observations that make you think that "This doesn't seem to be copying over the bytes how I want it to."

Comment: Probably you are facing endianness issues here.

Comment: @TarekDakhran Possible, lets wait for some details by OP.

Comment: John, on the totally tangential pilosophical topic of whether something like "question noobishness" even exists: We do not tolerate it! We exterminate it *Muhahahaha*. Not. I hope you see that we prevent it by helping you improve your question. It is not bad, also a little interesting. Just provide a little more info and details. It might then have a duplicate proposed. That would mean it is not bad at all, just already asked similarily. So, don't be afraid. Just work with us. We want to help. We just explain the rules if we think we have to.

Comment: "This doesn't seem to be copying over the bytes how I want it to" lacks info.  What data was attempted, what was the result and hoped for result?

Comment: With regards to _I want to put it into a char array with 16 characters (even if the char pointer's strlen() is greater than that_ note that even when `strlen(pointer_to_char) == 16`, a char array that can hold 16 characters is one element (byte) fewer than what you need.  `strlen` does not account for the NUL character at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer-arithmetic is what you might need to understand. When you declare an array of type uint32_t, compiler automatically does the magic under the hood to perform increments in the order of 4 bytes. Refer to example below

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<stdint.h>
 char* pointer = "HelloWorld!Hell!";
 uint32_t arr[4];
 unsigned char myArray[16];
 int main(void) {
     memcpy(arr, pointer, (size_t)16);
     //Generates warning but still works, because format is an indication to printf
     // how to deal with this array.
     printf("%s\n", arr); 
     char *arr1 = (char *)arr;

     for(int i = 0 ; i < 16; i++)
     {
         printf("arr[%d]=%c\n", i, arr1[i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: "//Generates warning but still works" --> Yes _undefined behavior_ (UB) sometimes "works", but makes for unreliable code.  Not a good solution.

Comment: What is the UB here ?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", arr);` expects a character pointer.  `arr`, as a function argument, is a `uint32t *`. These pointers are not specified as being the same size nor same form. "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined" C17dr § 7.21.6.1 9.  Could use `printf("%s\n", *char*) arr);`.  For more detail, suggest posting as a question.

Comment: Question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60591150/copying-a-string-literal-to-an-uint32-t-array-and-accessing-it

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems the `memcpy` works (maybe some endiannes issues as it was noted in the comments), but also you could just use a loop if you will.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[16] = {1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7, -8, 9, -10, 11, -12, 13, -14, 15, -16};
    uint32_t newArray[4];
    uint32_t otherArray[4];

    memcpy(newArray, arr, 16);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      printf("%d %d %d %d ", (char)(newArray[i] & 0xFF),
                             (char)((newArray[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8),
                             (char)((newArray[i] & 0xFF0000) >> 16),
                             (char)((newArray[i] & 0xFF000000) >> 24));

    putchar('\n');

    // Copy via loop using bitwise OR and shifting
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 4)
      otherArray[i / 4] = (((uint32_t)arr[i + 3]) << 24) & 0xFF000000 |
                          (((uint32_t)arr[i + 2]) << 16) & 0xFF0000   |
                          (((uint32_t)arr[i + 1]) << 8)  & 0xFF00     |
                          (uint32_t)arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      printf("%d %d %d %d ", (char)(otherArray[i] & 0xFF),
                             (char)((otherArray[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8),
                             (char)((otherArray[i] & 0xFF0000) >> 16),
                             (char)((otherArray[i] & 0xFF000000) >> 24));

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1 -2 3 -4 5 -6 7 -8 9 -10 11 -12 13 -14 15 -16 
1 -2 3 -4 5 -6 7 -8 9 -10 11 -12 13 -14 15 -16
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica 2) Yes I was lazy on this I admit, corrected it 1) You sure ? Changed the code and it seems to work (only printing needed adjustment). Or am I oversee something?

Comment: Ohh you right I overlooked that badly... Fixed it. Now it should really work I guess.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ohh you right because the implicit int promotion... hope I fixed it.

Comment: Good enough.  Another way: `((uint32_t)(unsigned char)arr[i + 3]) << 24)`.