# Copying a string literal to an uint32_t array and accessing it

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I pasted below code else where but it was suggested as a bad solution. The standard has this to say about memcpy:

> "The memcpy function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the
>   object pointed to by s1. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior
>   is undefined."

and this about uint32_t:

> "The typedef name uintN_t designates an unsigned integer type with width N and no
>   padding bits. Thus, uint24_t denotes such an unsigned integer type with a width of
>   exactly 24 bits."

Are there any alignment issues ? I have always been using this on linux and never encountered any bugs or such. I only use bitwise ops for access when i had to worry about the endianness for example receiving data over a link from another architecture. Kindly throw some light.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<stdint.h>
 char* pointer = "HelloWorld!Hell!";
 uint32_t arr[4];
 unsigned char myArray[16];
 int main(void) {
     memcpy(arr, pointer, (size_t)16);

     // Is this illegal ? 
     char *arr1 = (char *)arr;

     for(int i = 0 ; i < 16; i++)
     {
         printf("arr[%d]=%c\n", i, arr1[i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that `sizeof("HelloWorld!Hell!")` is 17 so I don't know what terminates the `printf` apart from pure luck, but `memcpy` is usually the most standard-compliant approach to copy data from one representation to another.

Comment: It's not out of luck, bss data on linux is initialized to zeroes, and zero is ascii value for null byte AFAIK. But this is not what is being asked here. My bad for causing confusion.

Comment: Just as a side note: You can use [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) instead of [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) if the source and destination memory buffers overlap. In contrast to `memcpy`, `memmove` allows the buffers to overlap.

Comment: Note the `(size_t)` cast is not needed in `memcpy(arr, pointer, (size_t)16);`.  To quiet some pedantic compilers that warn about sign-ness, could use `16u`.  2nd alternative: `memcpy(arr, pointer, sizeof arr);`

Comment: @PiyushSingh: `sizeof(arr)` is 16 and you are storing 16 characters into the array, without the null terminator. The "bss data on linux" comment is irrelevant, it's the C standard which mandates that static and global variables are initialized to zero, so they will be zero unless you go out of your way to tell the compiler to violate this requirement. Since `memcpy` is fine and aliasing a pointer through `char*` is fine, this is (was, before the edit) your only problem, that's why I stated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `memcpy` is fine.  Where you have undefined behavior is here:

```
printf("%s\n", arr);
```

The `%s` format specifier expects a `char *` argument but you're passing a `uint32_t *`.  Such an argument mismatch is undefined behavior.  The two pointer types may have the same representation on your system, but that isn't necessarily true in general.

Even if the types matched, you would *still* have UB because `arr` isn't large enough to contain the string `"HelloWorld!Hell!"`.  This string (including the null terminating byte) is 17 bytes wide and so the null terminator isn't copied.  Then `printf` reads past the end of the array which is UB.

As an example, I modified the list of variables as follows:

```
 uint32_t x = 0x11223344;
 uint32_t arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
 uint32_t y = 0x55667788;
```

And got the following output:

```
HelloWorld!Hell!�wfU
```

As for this:

```
char *arr1 = (char *)arr;
```

This is legal because a pointer of one object type may be converted to a pointer to another object type.  Also, because the destination type is `char *`, it is legal to dereference that pointer to access the underlying bytes of the original object.

Comment: I re-edited my code snippet to indicate what i want to have clarity about. Does the typecasting an uni32_t * to char * illegal in this case ?